# Floating point rounding error php ...how can I make sure it works correctly?

Tags: php

I have the following function that determines if I sale is fully paid for. I don't remember why I did it this way, but it has been working so far and I don't remember why I had to do it this way.

```
function _payments_cover_total()
{
    //get_payments is a list of payment amounts such as:
    //10.20, 10.21, or even 10.1010101101 (10 decimals max) 

    $total_payments = 0;

    foreach($this->sale_lib->get_payments() as $payment)
    {
        $total_payments += $payment['payment_amount'];
    }

    //to_currency_no_money rounds total to 2 decimal places
    if (to_currency_no_money($this->sale_lib->get_total()) - $total_payments ) > 1e-6 ) )
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I am wondering if there is ever a case where due to a rounding error that this function would return false when it shouldn't.

The main part I have a question about is:

```
 > 1e-6
```

I think before I had, but it was causing problems in some cases.

```
> 0
```

Comment: Use `abs()`.... `abs(to_currency_no_money($this->sale_lib->get_total()) - $total_payments )) > 1e-6)`

Comment: @MarkBaker Why? (Genuine question - `abs()` has nothing to do with rounding, which is what is discussed in the question, but maybe you've spotted a need for it that you could explain further?)

Comment: As a rule of thumb, never store money amounts as floating point values; use an integer number of pence (or smaller division) and convert only for display. I realise this isn't something you can easily convert an existing project to, so more a tip for the future I guess.

Comment: @IMSoP `x-y` can give a positive or a negative result, but comparing `> 1e-6` only allows for a positive result - ie. x is fractionally greater than y - but what if y is fractionally greater than x, and the result of that subtraction is a tiny negative value? A rounding error could then return true when it should return false. Using `abs()` always ensures that the result of `abs(x-y)` is positive, so the greater than comparison is a valid test whether x>y or y>x

Comment: I only need it for positive. Will this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are doing what is mentioned on [php floating](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#language.types.float.comparison) help page. To quote it directly :

> To test floating point values for equality, an upper bound on the
>   relative error due to rounding is used. This value is known as the
>   machine epsilon, or unit roundoff, and is the smallest acceptable
>   difference in calculations.

```
$a and $b are equal to 5 digits of precision.

<?php
$a = 1.23456789;
$b = 1.23456780;
$epsilon = 0.00001;

if(abs($a-$b) < $epsilon) {
    echo "true";
}
?>
```

So in your case:

`(to_currency_no_money($this->sale_lib->get_total()) - $total_payments) > 1e-6`

**relative error due to rounding** should not be great than **1e-6** or **0.000001**

if you are not sure about left operand being greater than right 100% time,then you should add `abs()` e.g for correctness.

```
$relative_error=to_currency_no_money($this->sale_lib->get_total()) - $total_payments;
 if(abs($relative_error) > 1e-6){
   return false
 }
 return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = (1.333-1.233)-(1.334-1.234);
echo $x;

//result = $x = -2.2204460492503E-16 - close to zero
//but (1.333-1.233)-(1.334-1.234) = 0.1 - 0.1 = 0 (in calculator)

if($x === 0){
    echo "|zero";
}
else {
    echo "|non zero"; //<== this is result
}
//screen = -2.2204460492503E-16|non zero

//how to get to zero?

if($x > 1e-6){//1e-6 mathematical constant
    echo "|non zero";
}
else {
    echo "|zero";//this is result
}
//screen -2.2204460492503E-16|non zero|zero

if ($x > 1e-6 )
{
   echo " false";
    //echo "|non zero";
    //return false;
}
else{
    echo " true";//<== this resut
    //echo "|zero";
    //return true;
}
//screen -2.2204460492503E-16|non zero|zero true



printf("%.1f<br />", 1e-1);
printf("%.2f<br />", 1e-2);
printf("%.3f<br />", 1e-3);
printf("%.4f<br />", 1e-4);
printf("%.5f<br />", 1e-5);
printf("%.6f<br />", 1e-6);
printf("%.7f<br />", 1e-7);
printf("%.8f<br />", 1e-8);
printf("%.9f<br />", 1e-9);
printf("%.10f<br />", 1e-10);
printf("%.11f<br />", 1e-11);
printf("%.12f<br />", 1e-12);
printf("%.29f<br />", -2.2204460492503E-16);
//0.1
//0.01
//0.001
//0.0001
//0.00001
//0.000001
//0.0000001
//0.00000001
//0.000000001
//0.0000000001
//0.00000000001
//0.000000000001
//-0.00000000000000022204460492503
```

Comment: SO is 1e-6 safe for values close to zero (float rounding as shown above)?

Comment: If you are working on floating-point types, then you have to accept
himself a margin of error, for example 1e-6. Precision to 1e-6 = 0.00001.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, but when dealing with currency, you shouldn't really be using PHP floats, as IMSoP stated. The reason is also from PHP float help pages:

> Additionally, rational numbers that are exactly representable as
>   floating point numbers in base 10, like 0.1 or 0.7, do not have an
>   exact representation as floating point numbers in base 2, which is
>   used internally, no matter the size of the mantissa. Hence, they
>   cannot be converted into their internal binary counterparts without a
>   small loss of precision. This can lead to confusing results: for
>   example, floor((0.1+0.7)*10) will usually return 7 instead of the
>   expected 8, since the internal representation will be something like
>   7.9999999999999991118....
>
> So never trust floating number results to the last digit, and do not
>   compare floating point numbers directly for equality. If higher
>   precision is necessary, the arbitrary precision math functions and gmp
>   functions are available.

Note that the help page specifically says you *can't* trust float results to the last digit, **no matter how short (after comma) it is**.

So while you do have very short floats (just 2 digits after comma), the float precision (1e-6) doesn't enter into it really, and you can't trust them 100%.

Since it is a question of money, in order to avoid angry customers and lawsuits accusing of penny shaving (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salami_slicing), the real solutions are:

1) either use PHP BC math, which works with string representation of numbers
http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php

2) as IMSoP suggested, use integers and store the amounts in smallest denomination (cents, eurocents or whatever you have) internally.

First solution might be a bit more resource intense: I haven't used BC math myself much, but storing strings and doing arbitrary precision math (which might be a bit of an overkill in this case) are by definition more RAM and CPU intense than working with integers.

It might, however, need less changes in other parts of the code.

The second solution requires changes to represenation, so that wherever user sees the amounts, they are normalized to dollars,cents (or whatever have you).

Note, however, that in this case also you run problems with rounding risks at some point, as when you do:

```
float shown_amount; // what we show to customer: in dollars,cents
int real_amount; // what we use internally: in cents
shown_amount = cent_amount / 100;
```

you may reintroduce the rounding problems as you have floats again and possibilities for rounding errors, so tread carefully and be sure to make calculations and roundings only on real_amount, never on shown_amount